# What is a more sophisticated way of saying "grand finale"?

Tags: synonyms

I want to say big deal/grand finale, but more professionally.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. *Big deal* is probably always slangy and/or facetious, but surely *grand finale* is formal and "sophisticated". I can't say it's more "professional" without knowing at least something about the context, and what exactly OP wants his expression to refer to.

Comment: *Sophisticated*, *big deal* and *grand finale* are not quite the same or in a class. Not  real Q. Voting to close.

Comment: How about **fanfare**? Or **overture**? I realise these are more about the beginnings of things, rather than the ends, but they may convey the grandiosity you are after.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not entirely clear, but perhaps you are thinking of terms like *[last hurrah](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/last_hurrah?rdfrom=Last_Hurrah)* ("A final act (by a politician etc.) or performance (by an actor etc.) that marks the end of a career") and *[swan song](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swan_song)* ("A final performance or accomplishment, especially one before retirement").

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, you might consider *pièce de résistance*.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi%C3%A8ce_de_r%C3%A9sistance) says this phrase "gives the sense that the referred-to element is the most outstanding, notable, or defining of the collection."  Though literally French, the term is used in English. Definitions from [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/pi%C3%A8ce%20de%20r%C3%A9sistance):

> #### Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia
>
> The most important piece or feature; the show piece; the main event or incident in any round or series, as the most forcible article in a magazine, the principal exhibition or performance in a show or theatrical entertainment, or the most substantial dish in a dinner.
>
> #### Wiktionary
>
> n. A masterpiece; the most memorable accomplishment of one’s career or lifetime.